# jupyter notebook loading its previous version

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using latest version of python 3.11.4 and i have installed jupyter notebook using pip, but when i open the jupyter notebook using "jupyter-notebook" command it shows some older version of jupyter notebook.

These are the version installed in my computer: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi0AI.png). The jupyter dashboard looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuqtb.png) and notebook looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfRrK.png) this.

Comment: You've got environment issues that you are not understanding. You may be better off installing [the Anaconda distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/index.html) and using that to launch and manage your environments so you can track the versions better.

Comment: @Wayne installing Anaconda was a great idea, it works as i was asking